# Add directories to ASP.NET shadow copy via webconfig

Tags: asp.net, web-config, shadow-copy

Is there anyway to mark a folder (other than `Bin` folder) to be shadow copied by adding some configurations in `web.config` ?

I don't think `Application_Start` be a good place for setting up `AppDomainSetup.ShadowCopyDirectories` because at that point `AppDomain` is already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct once the app domain is created changing the shadow directory location is not possible. You would need to create a separate app domain to point at a different directory. Since bin is shadow copied anyway why not add a sub directory in bin with your additional content ?

Comment: If I'm not wrong the default shadow copy mechanism followed by ASP .Net works only for managed .Net assemblies present in `bin` directory and its sub-directories. Kindly correct me if I'm wrong.